# Compile-time singleton more-than-one-time-instantiation detection

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is it possible to create a template meta construction that can take one execution path first time (or first n times) it is called and another execution path if it is called more than once (more then n times)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch A little example? Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Templates are evaluated at compile time only.

The question is about things that happen at run-time (execution path).
Now it should be very possible to build this construct in code, but it is not a template meta-construct (though it can be part of a template meta-program, but the code that does the test will be runtime code (ie normal code)).

Comment: But the compiler would optimize instanciations of e.g. `if` with a a constant template argument, etc.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: As you elude too in your comment (the compiler would optimize) It can not evaluate stuff at run time. Template evaluation is done at compile time only.

Comment: Yet, it would optimize constants away (hopefully) and eliminate paths that can't be reached in a particular instance. However, the variable indicating whether this is the first or another instance is not a constant.

Answer (score 2):

**What you can achieve with templates is compile time decision of path, like in this example with using of template specialization:**

```
template <bool whichOne>
class ExecutionExampleImpl;

template <>
class ExecutionExampleImpl<true> {
public:
  static void doIt() {
    std::cout << "Do it for the first time(s)\n";   
  }
};

template <>
class ExecutionExampleImpl<false> {
public:
  static void doIt() {
    std::cout << "Do it for the second time(s)\n";   
  }
};


template <unsigned execution>
void executionExample()
{
   const unsigned ExecutionExampleFirstLimit = 3;

   ExecutionExampleImpl<execution <= ExecutionExampleFirstLimit>::doIt();
}

int main() {
   executionExample<1>();
   executionExample<2>();
   executionExample<3>();
   executionExample<4>();
   executionExample<5>();
   executionExample<6>();
}
```

---

---

**However I believe you you would prefer runtime decision. You can make this with static local variable:**

```
void executionExample()
{
   const unsigned ExecutionExampleFirstLimit = 3;
   static unsigned executionCounter = 0;
   if (executionCounter++ <  ExecutionExampleFirstLimit)
   {
      std::cout << "Do it for the first time(s)\n";   
   }
   else
   {
       std::cout << "Do it for the second time(s)\n";   
   }
}

int main() {
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
      executionExample();
}
```

Comment: executionExample<1>() and executionExample<2>() and the others are all different functions. Each of these functions is taking exactly the same path every time it is executed.

Comment: @Predrag For `1,2,3` they go one path for `4,5,6,....` they go the other path. See compile time condition `execution <= ExecutionExampleFirstLimit`.  But indeed they are different functions doing either one or other task.

Answer (score 1):

The question matches two aparently unrelated things: templates are *instantiated* (not *executed*) by the compiler and the required instances are *excecuted* at run-time by the machine (not the compiler).

What you can do is make a template that instantiate differently depending on a constant value. And if those instances are recursive you have a sort of "compile time execution" that decide what to instantiate.

[std::conditional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) can be a good sample.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, whether a particular path is followed, and how many times, may be decided at runtime--if the function call is in the body of an `if` statement, to take one obvious example.  However any construction for dictating the flow of execution which relied on templates (and their parameters) would have to know this at compile time.  So no, it can't be done.